# Double indexing in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to extract a piece of information, num_buy_ratings, from a dictionary as follows:

In the first case, the dictionary is like

```
buy = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings(symbol, info='summary')  
Out[96]: 
    {'summary': {'num_buy_ratings': 4,
      'num_hold_ratings': 2,
      'num_sell_ratings': 1},
     'ratings': [],
     'instrument_id': '4d591f16-7f0a-4fe7-a369-5346a61c0dfb',
     'ratings_published_at': None}
```

The next case, the dictionary is like

```
buy = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings(symbol, info='summary')
Out[99]: {'num_buy_ratings': 25, 'num_hold_ratings': 12, 'num_sell_ratings': 4}
```

How do I access num_buy_ratings with one command instead of double-indexing in the 1st case and single-indexing in the latter?

Comment: are you saying the API for this package you are using does not return consistent results? that doesn't seem right...

Comment: @gold_cy you are 100% that it doesn’t seem right, but I have seen it before with market data providers. It’s sloppy work and will drive developers out of their minds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would write a nasty email to the designer of the API and tell them to be consistent in their data model.

In the mean time I would something like this:

```
def process_summary(buy):
    if 'summary' in buy.keys():
        return buy['summary']
    else:
        return buy

>>> buy1={'summary': {'num_buy_ratings': 4,
...       'num_hold_ratings': 2,
...       'num_sell_ratings': 1},
...      'ratings': [],
...      'instrument_id': '4d591f16-7f0a-4fe7-a369-5346a61c0dfb',
...      'ratings_published_at': None}
>>> buy2={'num_buy_ratings': 25, 'num_hold_ratings': 12, 'num_sell_ratings': 4}
```

Usage and output:

```
>>> process_summary(buy1)
{'num_buy_ratings': 4, 'num_hold_ratings': 2, 'num_sell_ratings': 1}
>>> process_summary(buy2)
{'num_buy_ratings': 25, 'num_hold_ratings': 12, 'num_sell_ratings': 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
d = {'summary': {'num_buy_ratings': 4,
      'num_hold_ratings': 2,
      'num_sell_ratings': 1},
     'ratings': [],
     'instrument_id': '4d591f16-7f0a-4fe7-a369-5346a61c0dfb',
     'ratings_published_at': None}

print( d.get('summary', d)['num_buy_ratings'] )
```

Prints:

```
4
```

---

For `d = {'num_buy_ratings': 25, 'num_hold_ratings': 12, 'num_sell_ratings': 4}`:

```
print( d.get('summary', d)['num_buy_ratings'] )
```

Prints:

```
25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple function if you only have the two exact cases you gave:

```
def get_num_buy_ratings(d:dict) -> Any:
    if 'num_buy_ratings' in d:
        return d['num_buy_ratings']
    else:
        return d['summary']['num_buy_ratings']
```

If there are arbitrarily deeply nested dictionaries, you could use the following recursive algorithm to find a given key-value-pair if it existsts:

```
def find_value(d:dict, search_key:str) -> Tuple(bool, Any): 
    subdicts = [] 
    found = False 
    result = None 
    for key in d: 
        #print(f'key: {key}') 
        if key == search_key: 
            print('key found!') 
            result = d[search_key] 
            found = True 
            break 
        elif isinstance(d[key], dict): 
            subdicts.append(d[key]) 
    else: 
        for subdict in subdicts: 
            found, result = find_value(subdict, search_key) 
            if found: 
                break 
    return found, result
```